# How to avoid loading whole data while searching in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I search through large data using `AngularJS` only when I type >3 chars in input.

```
var app = angular.module('test_table', []);
app.controller('main_control',function($scope, $http){
    $scope.inputChange = function(){
        if($scope.search.length > 3){
            $http.get("http://localhost:7001/load").success(function(data){
                $scope.loaded=data; 
            });
        }
        if($scope.search.length < 4){
            $http.get("http://localhost:7001/load").success(function(data){
                $scope.loaded=""; 
            });
        }
    }       
});
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="search" class="inputsearchform" ng-model="search" ng-change="inputChange()"/>
...
<tr class="rowR" ng-repeat="data in loaded | filter:{song_name: search}">
```

I have problem. When I type more than 3 chars and then delete everything using default button in input, the whole data is loaded to the page, and it cause a big delay. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the following:

```
if($scope.search.length == 0){
      $scope.loaded=""; 
}
```

or create a function triggered by the delete button:

```
$scope.delete = function(){ 
      $scope.loaded=""; 
}
```

**PS**: You shouldn't call a service if you are going to assign an empty variable:

```
        if($scope.search.length < 4){
            $http.get("http://localhost:7001/load").success(function(data){
                $scope.loaded=""; 
            });
        }
```

should really be:

```
        if($scope.search.length < 4){
                $scope.loaded=""; 
        }
```

**PS 2**: `if($scope.search.length < 4)` doesn't really make sense either because if there are 3 chars - this if statement would be satisfied as eluded to by @aw04

Comment: Is there a reason not to just remove the http call on < 4 rather than create another condition? I can't see the point in it

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid the delay, you will have to limit the data you are rendering.For this you can use the angular filter `limitTo`. Set the limitTo to any value which you want to load for default.

Comment: if you're trying to limit the data for performance reasons, it would make more sense to limit it on the server

Comment: @aw04 what do you mean by this? Because I want to increase performance. What can you advise for it?

Comment: @LevS So what this answer is saying is to limit the data, which would mean you need to add paging or some sort of load more functionality. My point was that doing this in angular wouldn't help as much because you're still loading all the data from the server, which likely takes much more time than the rendering

Comment: @LevS Having said that, if you build something into your server to only grab x records at a time (then again, paging or load more), this could potentially improve performance considerably

Comment: @aw04 Now I load only whole data from server and then search in it with angular. So, performance is not so good as it can be. What do you mean? To load some part from server, i.e. 1/10 of it, than search in it, show results on page/pages and then load again second part and repeat. Am I right?

Comment: @LevS More or less, yes. You can research server side paging and see if it's a fit for what you're doing. I would only recommend this if your performance problem is a result of the amount of data coming from the server.

Comment: @aw04 Thanks for explanation!